# How to make full-width divs in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap in a project of mine. I am making divs inside columns but they are not apreading acrosss the full-width of the columns.

This is a sample code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <style type="text/css">
    .col{
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
    <div class="col col-lg-2">
      <div class="blue" style="background-color: blue;">
        1 of 3
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-auto">
      Variable width content
    </div>
    <div class="col col-lg-2">
      3 of 3
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      1 of 3
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-auto">
      Variable width content
    </div>
    <div class="col col-lg-2">
      3 of 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My question is simple:
"How do I make my `<div class="blue">` across 100% width of the original column?"

I also tried setting width to 100%.

**UPDATE**

I used `<div class="row no-gutters">` instead of `<div class="row">` and removed the `container-fluid`. **Worked like a charm**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
you have to use this class in row

"row no-gutters justify-content-md-center"
```

Answer (score 0):

You want each div to take up 100% of the column? if so, your divs are currently set to `col-2`, perhaps you should set them to `col-12` (with the desired viewport prefix, lg, md, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a CSS issue. By default, columns in the Bootstrap Grid System have 100% width.

My only recommendation would be to check your CSS for the "blue" class. It would need to be:

```
.blue{
    margin: 0px;
    ...
}
```

I would also try changing the following in your HTML

```
<div class="row justify-content-md-center">
```

to just

```
<div class="row">
```

and set the justify-content in your CSS file and see if that helps